# I am confused by a certain variable in Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am writing a messaging application, and am wanting to add authentication, but I have no clue what a certain variable in Firebase is a placeholder for, and would like some help with what this variable is. The name of the variable is "TAG".

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
        }
    };

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Comment: See the first tip: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Answer (score 1):

`TAG` is a `static final String` that is used to label Logcat messages. Just create a field in the activity

```
public static final String TAG = "MyLogs";
```

and you'll be good to go